# angularJS $states optimization issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically, my question is about angular $state optimization. I have a small project, and every time a call a certain state, which have around 9 objects to resolve, it takes about 3-4 seconds to load a page. I thought the problem is with a states, so I decided to resolve only one object with data of that 9, instead of resolving those 9. But I realized that it still takes around 3-4 seconds for page to load. Is there a way to optimize angular code, so that it loads faster.

```
resolve: {

                // Countries: function (msApi)
                // {
                //     return msApi.resolve('countries@query');
                // },
                // Nationalities: function (msApi)
                // {                        
                //     return msApi.request('nationalities@query');
                // },
                // EmploymentStatuses: function (msApi)
                // {                        
                //     return msApi.request('employment-statuses@query');
                // },
                // Industries: function (msApi)
                // {                        
                //     return msApi.request('employment-industries@query');
                // },
                // JobFunctions: function (msApi)
                // {                        
                //     return msApi.request('employment-jobfunctions@query');
                // },
                // EducationLevels: function (msApi)
                // {                        
                //     return msApi.request('employment-educationlevels@query');
                // },
                // FieldOfStudy: function (msApi)
                // {                        
                //     return msApi.request('employment-fieldofstudy@query');
                // },
                SkillList: function (msApi)
                {                        
                    return msApi.request('employment-skilllist@query');
                },   

                //All Requests in One
                ResumeData: function (msApi)
                {                        
                    return msApi.request('resume-entry-requests@get');
                }, 
            }
```

Those commented, is obtained by ResumeData. Also the view page has quite a number of ng-repeats, can this be an issue ? If yes is there any other way to replace ng-repeat to populate selects and other components to improve the performance?

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: having multiple ng-repeats is not a big issue if you have used one way binding for them, however resolving those 9 objects separately may help, I mean resolving one and let the UI render that (a loading is displayed while others are being resolved)

Comment: And just offtop question, does angular 2 handle all this better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);` (http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/14/exploring-angular-1.3-speed-up-with-applyAsync.html) for speeding up multiple requests.

And, you can create a cache service, that will hold data for, lets say 5 minutes, so when user switches states, it will fetch the data from js object in the memory and not the server.

Unfortunately, that is all I can think of right now, as for http calls performance. If is takes 4 second by itself, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: The thing is the view page has multiple components and for each component data filled up differently. I was thinking, is there any tool to optimize js code itself? Will it help ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the multiple components thing. The cache object in the cache service would store all the data and the cache service would make $http call, so it's not a problem. Or am I missing something? The code you provided is OK.

Comment: You say you got a lot of ng-repeats... when talking about hunderds of items, you can use some kind of pagination to speed things up a bit. Also track by ... trick would be nice, one time binding... It is hard to tell

Comment: The whole application is made using a fuse angular template, which is based on angular material. Could that be an issue ?

Comment: I'd start by measuring the time the backend takes to respond.

Comment: Backend return values less than in a second actually. I think its front end side issue

Comment: And are you sure you're not doing any useless computations? Also try putting less items to the DOM at a time and using some kind of pagination maybe?